# how could I change the format of every image in an array in python?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, opencv, face-recognition, generative-adversarial-network

i know it sounds simple but I do not know what am i doing wrong, I'm trying to make a face detection model using GAN (Generative Adversive Networks) I don´t know if it will work but first I need to put all the images in the format (-1,28,28,1) this is what I have:

```
data = np.load('training_images_full.npz', allow_pickle=True)

images = data['images']

pts = data['points']

x_data = images.astype("float32") / 255

x_data = np.reshape(x_data, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
```

#this is where it gives me the error

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 280166400 into shape (28,28,1)`
```

Any idea?

i've changed the order, i´ve made loops, this is the way I was taught and it does not work now and I don't know why, Maybe the GAN accepts the shape of the actual images but I do not knwo where to change it I DO NOT SEE WHERE IT SAYS THAT IT EXPECTS IMAGES OF THAT SHAPE. The GAN works with tensorflow. My first idea was to make the GAN that trains with the data points that are already in the images, and then based on the image you give it will guess where the landmarks are located, but first I wanted to try it with the images. If you know a video or a paper or something that explains GAN not in a completely scientific extra difficult way it would be really helpfull too.  Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Tell us about `images`. `shape` and `dtype`

Comment: You are using a GAN to detect faces? I don't think a GAN will help you with that. If you want to program it from scratch, you will need a CNN with regression that predicts bounding boxes coordinates.

Comment: @hpaulj print(images.shape)      (1425, 256, 256, 3)

Comment: your images are 256x256 pixel and they are rgb. you have to dowscale them to 28x28 and greyscale or use a bigger input to you neural network. atm you are trying to reshape a 256x256x3 pixel image into a 28x28x1 pixel image which is not working